# Hibernate/JPA query language new entity constructor with subquery - unable to locate appropriate constructor

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I have an order and an order fraud alert. The association runs only from the fraud alert to the order, not vice versa.

```
public class FraudAlerts
...
@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "customerOrderId")
private CustomerOrder customerOrder;
```

My query is this:

```
"select new com.acme.struts.search.FraudOrderSearchViewModel"
+ "(co.orderId, co.orderPlacedDate, tot.totalIncVat, adr.email, co.customerNumber, co.ipAddress, "
+ "(select name from FraudAlerts where co.orderId = customerOrder))"
+ " from CustomerOrder as co join co.customerBillTo adr join co.originalTotal as tot");
```

You can see I use subquery to get all fraudAlert names that that are accociated with this order as a collection and pass that to the view model bean FraudOrderSearchViewModel.

My problem is that hibernate won't find the appropriate constructor for it and throws an exception:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: Unable to locate appropriate constructor on class [com.acme.struts.search.FraudOrderSearchViewModel] [select new com.acme.struts.search.FraudOrderSearchViewModel(co.orderId, co.orderPlacedDate, tot.totalIncVat, adr.email, co.customerNumber, co.ipAddress, (select name from com.acme.data.model.fraud.FraudAlerts where co.orderId = customerOrder)) from com.acme.data.model.customer.CustomerOrder as co join co.customerBillTo adr join co.originalTotal as tot]
at org.hibernate.ejb.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.convert(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1364)
at org.hibernate.ejb.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.convert(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1300)
at org.hibernate.ejb.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.createQuery(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:294)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
at org.springframework.orm.jpa.SharedEntityManagerCreator$SharedEntityManagerInvocationHandler.invoke(SharedEntityManagerCreator.java:240)
at $Proxy65.createQuery(Unknown Source)
at com.acme.services.fraud.FraudHibQueryTest.testFraudServiceHibQuery(FraudHibQueryTest.java:72)
```

My constructor is the following:

```
    public FraudOrderSearchViewModel(final String orderId, final Date datePlaced, final BigDecimal originalTotal, final String customerEmail, final String customerId,
        final String ipAddress, final Object[] holdReason)
```

I tried String[], List List to no avail. What is the type of constructor variable that hibernate wants me to use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I turns out I just hit a limitation in the relational model. I was trying to get a list of DB rows where each one would contain a column consisting itself of multiple rows from another table. It is just not possible to do with one query.

Answer (score -1):

Your hibernate entity `FraudOrderSearchViewModel` should have a default no argument constructor.

Comment: Thanks, but it has one, that is not the problem. Similar queries where no subquery is involved, only simple types, all work perfectly.

Answer (score -1):

one cause of this problem is the order in which you retrieve the columns from the table in your query. it must be the same as in the constructor.